# What exactly does $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ calculate in implicit differentiation? (details given)

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Does it calculate the derivative of the given equation?
Because in implicit differentiation we don't have $y= equation$ so I don't know what we are differentiating using the $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$

Do we consider/assume the given equation lets say $x^2+y^2=36$ as $y$ when we say calculate $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$?
Does it mean we just have to differentiate the given equation and $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is its derivative or the gradient function?
This question might seem redundant but I swear nobody asks this question, its a really dumb thing that I don't know or can't seem to understand.

Comment: In terms of an application that requires implicit differentiation, are you looking for the physical meaning of it?

Comment: nope, just what $\frac{d}{dx}$ (y) is in the equation $x^2+y^2=36$ is it its derivative? i am just confused because in explicit it is stated that y = something something so when dy/dx is used i know that it means to differentiate the equation but here i get confused as it is not stated *explicitly*

Comment: It will essentially calculate the usual derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ (slopes of tangents to the curve), where **we view $y$ as a function of $x$** in the given curve. For example, if $x^2+y^2=36$, then implicit differentiation gives $2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=0\Rightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}$. Now if you have a point on the curve, you can plug it into this to obtain the *slope of the tangent to the curve there*. For example at the point $(0,6)$, the slope of the tangent to the curve is $-\frac{0}{6}=0$, i.e. a horizontal tangent (which makes perfect sense if you graph this circle!).

Comment: What's actually going on is: *by magic*, the abstract equation $x^2+y^2=36$ has a local solution, when $|x|\neq6$, $f$. $f$ is a *differentiable function* and it will be true that, for $x$ in the domain of $f$ (which maybe is quite small, who knows) we have $x^2+f(x)^2=36$. More can be said; for solutions $(x,y)$ to the equation that are nearby the initial condition, it must be the case that $y=f(x)$. So what we are doing is differentiating the *local parametrisation* of the solution set. Such a mysterious function $f$, or "$y(x)$" if you like, exists and that's what we are differentiating.

Comment: It's not a really dumb thing. Implicit differentiation is rarely explained correctly at pre-university level. One day maybe you'll study the implicit function theorem and hopefully what's going on will really, truly make sense. It didn't for me, until I studied the theorem and its proof

Comment: so it's a different imaginary function altogether?

Comment: In this case we can say quite explicitly, $f(x)=\sqrt{36-x^2}$ or $f(x)=-\sqrt{36-x^2}$. Most of the time though we cannot write down a clear formula for $f$. However, we can still prove it exists. But *because we don't know what $f$ really looks like*, we need to use *implicit* differentiation to study $f$ (rather than *explicit* differentiation, which is what you do to formulas by applying rules like $d/dx [ x^5 ] = 5x^4$)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An equation of the form $f(x,y)=0$ describes a set of points in the plane $\mathbb R^2.$ Usually (but not always) this set consists of some curves. At a point on such a curve, we can, unless the tangent is vertical, find a neighborhood in which there are no distinct points with the same value of $y$. The curve segment in that neighborhood is the graph of some function $y=g(x).$ What we calculate with implicit differentiation is the derivative of that function: $\frac{dy}{dx}=g'(x).$

Here's a quadrifolium, the solution to $(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3}=a^{2}(x^{2}-y^{2})^{2}.$ It isn't the graph of any function $x\mapsto y$ globally, but locally, for example inside the red circle, it can be written as $y=g(x).$ (We might not be able to find an explicit expression for $g(x)$ though.) That part of the graph is smooth and using implicit differentiation we can find $g'(x).$

[image: quadrifolium with a neighborhood where we have a graph of a function]

Comment: I understand some part of this, thank you very much. Do you recommend looking into some materials or videos
 to understand it better? @md2perpe

Comment: @ATS. Unfortunately I don't have any specific recommendations. You can look around on YouTube. There are videos about _implicit differentiation_.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same thing it always means, the slope of the tangent line to the curve that is the graph of the equation.

"Implicit" differentiation just has to do with how you differentiate the expressions. The meaning of the derivative is the same.

You need to be careful about how you say it -- you aren't taking the derivative of the ***equation***, you're differentiating the ***expressions*** on each side of the equation.

For example, you can rewrite the equation $y=f(x)$ as $\frac{f(x)}{y}=1$ and use implicit differentiation to find $dy/dx$:
$$\require{cancel}\frac{f(x)}{y}=1$$ $$\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg(\frac{f(x)}{y}\Bigg) = \frac{d}{dx}\Bigg(1\Bigg)$$
$$\frac{y\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)] - f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[y]}{y^2} = 0$$
$$\frac{y\cdot f'(x) - f(x)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}}{y^2}= 0$$
$$y\cdot f'(x) - f(x)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\cancel{y}\cdot f'(x)}{\cancel{f(x)}}=f'(x)$$

Comment: "the meaning of the derivative is the same" - $y$ is not a given function, so, the meaning isn't really the same. We are secretly also saying "there is a local parametrisation of the pairs $(x,y)$ and .... and ... and *that's* the thing we're differentiating". So "$y$" has to be understood in a more subtle way, if you want to view it as a function.

Comment: so $dy/dx$ is an equation or fraction really that we get after implicitly differentiating an equation and we can know the slopes of the tangents formed at those points by putting in the value

Comment: The derivative is always determined locally. In the case of implicit differentiation, you are differentiatiing an implicitly defined function. The meaning **is** the same. It is the slope of the tangent line.

Answer (score 0):

Is just the slope of the tangent line. It's closely tied to the gradient.

Suppose $f(x,y)=0$, e.g. $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 -R^2 =0$.

Then $\nabla f = 2x \hat{i} + 2y \hat{j}$

Let $d\vec{s} =dx \hat{i} + dy\hat{i}$

Then the chain rue tells us $df=\nabla f \cdot d\vec{s} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy =2xdx + 2ydy . $

And since $f\equiv 0, df\equiv 0. $

$2xdx + 2ydy =0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x}{y}$

---

You can see this is the slope in another way. Parameterize the curve.

Suppose we hae $x^2+y^2-9=0$.

Then we can let $x=3\cos  t . y= 3 \sin t$.

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-3\sin t=-y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=3\cos t = x$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}=\frac{x}{-y}=\frac{-x}{y}$

Here $t$ is just a parameter, you can think of it as time and then $x$ and $y$ give you position with respect to time, but what is the geometric meaning of $dx/dt$? Geometrically, not much, at least not directly, yet the ratio of y and  x velocity gives you the slope of the tangent line, a solidly geometric object.